# How to move parent div when hover to child image using jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two text box with an equalsign image. I need when the user hovers over equalsing image then he can move the div otherwise he can't move it.

I mean the user can move the div with the help of equal sign.
Would you help me?

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({});
    $( "#sortable1" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
.border-bg{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  width: 250px;
}
  #sortable1 img, #sortable2 img{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor:move;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="sortable1">
<div class="border-bg" >
<div class="" >
  <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Mathematic%20Equal%20sign2.ico">
  <label>name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
</div>
</div>

<div class="border-bg">
<div class="" >
  <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Mathematic%20Equal%20sign2.ico">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I need when the user hovers over equalsing image then he can move the div `-> ` hovers over` or `click`, because  on ` hovers over` you can't do that, what i think

Comment: You can move whole div or only inputbox..?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I mean drag and drop.When user trying to drag and drop then he can do only with image.

Comment: @ankitapatel, You can check my snippet. I need same but from Image, the user can move it. Now It's moving when drag and drop anywhere of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass handle option for sortable with selector to be used like below
or use some class name for images and use it.

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
         handle: "img"
    });
```

Comment: It's working, but I just need one information that, If I set two images inside #sortable1 than? It will effect on both, right?

Comment: yes it will affect both. handle needs a jquery selector so technically you can select multiple elments  you can read more on this at http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle